# Undefined reference error to glib components even with glib included

Tags: compiling, c, xubuntu

Just starting out with Xubuntu 14.04 on a refurbished machine (2GB mem, 2GHz dual core), and have a cursory/reading knowledge of c, but am not a c programmer.

I'm trying to compile code I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15971/getting-visual-feedback-of-workspace-switch-in-xfce) to create a visual notification for the action of moving between workspaces.  The code:

```
// wschanged.c
#include <libwnck/libwnck.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void
on_active_workspace_changed (WnckScreen    *screen,
                             WnckWorkspace *space,
                             gpointer      data)
{
    // Executes a script on workspace change
    system ("~/.workspace-changed");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

   GMainLoop *loop;   
   WnckScreen *screen;

   glib:gdk_init (&argc, &argv);

   loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
   screen = wnck_screen_get_default();

   g_signal_connect (screen, "active-workspace-changed",
                    G_CALLBACK (on_active_workspace_changed), NULL);

   g_main_loop_run (loop);
   g_main_loop_unref (loop);    

   return 0;
}
```

The compile command:

```
gcc -O2 -DWNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE -o wschanged `pkg-config  --cflags --libs libwnck-3.0` wschanged.c
```

The errors I'm receiving:

```
wschanged.c: In function ‘on_active_workspace_changed’:
wschanged.c:12:12: warning: ignoring return value of ‘system’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     system ("~/.workspace-changed");
            ^
/tmp/ccR60OkB.o: In function `main':
wschanged.c:(.text.startup+0x16): undefined reference to `gdk_init'
wschanged.c:(.text.startup+0x1f): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_new'
wschanged.c:(.text.startup+0x27): undefined reference to `wnck_screen_get_default'
wschanged.c:(.text.startup+0x41): undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
wschanged.c:(.text.startup+0x49): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_run'
wschanged.c:(.text.startup+0x51): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_unref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the latest version of libwnck, and I've also added:

```
#include <glib.h>
```

to see if this would fix the errors seeming to stem from undefined references to objects in the glib package, but this has not changed any of the error output.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of arguments to `gcc` is significant, so you need to split the `--cflags` and `--libs` variants of the `pkg-config` invocations:

```
gcc -O2 -DWNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE -o wschanged `pkg-config --cflags libwnck-3.0` wschanged.c `pkg-config --libs libwnck-3.0`
```